# How do I turn of the blanking of the screen in GNOME 3?

Tags: fedora-15, gnome3

I want to use my Fedora 15 in a kiosk mode displaying the screen on a TV.

My problem is that the screen goes blank after a little while.
The system is running GNOME 3 as window manager.

In the configuration settings for the screen there is only possible to change the time before the screen goes blank. I can not configure it to 'never'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer at [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749126).
Basically use the two commands:

1. gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
2. xset -dpms

The last command needs to be added to session properties to be executed each time you login.

Comment: Since I gave this answer, I found a shell extension called Caffeine that works very good. You find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/